# Question on rectangular hyperbola and its focus and directrix.

Tags: contest-math, circles, conic-sections

> Let S be the focus of the hyperbola $xy=1$. Let a tangent to the hyperbola at point P cuts the latus rectum (through S) produced, at point Q and the directrix (corresponding to S) at point T. Also let M be the foot of perpendicular drawn from the point P to the same directrix. If angle PTS=$\theta_1$ and angle PMS=$\theta_2$, find $\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}$ and $\frac{SQ}{ST}$

**My Attempt:**

I made the diagram and guess that P,M,T,S lies on a circle. Not sure though.

Tangent at P is $\frac{x}{x_1}+\frac{y}{y_1}=2$, where $(x_1,y_1)$ are the coordinates of P.

Taking x-axis as the directrix, PM=$y_1$, MT=$√2-x_1$

Taking S as $(√2,√2)$

Not able to proceed ahead.

Comment: HINT 1. Points $PMTS$ do lie on a circle, because of this:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360164/a-right-angle-at-the-focus-of-a-hyperbola

Comment: HINT 2. Triangles $MPS$ and $QST$ are similar.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca, thanks for the hints. I am able to work out Hint1. For Hint 2, I can see one pair of equal angles. Not able to prove triangles to be similar.

Comment: HINT 3. $PS\perp ST$ and $PM\perp SQ$, hence $\angle MPS =\dots$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca sorry not able to take the hint. Referring to the diagram below (Narasimham's answer), I can see that PS perpendicular to ST and PM perpendicular to SQ. Not able to see the relation with angle MPS here.

Comment: Rotate triangle $QST$ by $90°$, so that $Q$ is mapped to $Q'=M$: line $Q'S'$ is then the same as line $MP$ and line $S'T'$ parallel to $PS$. We have then $\angle MPS=\angle Q'S'T'=\angle QST$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca sorry to press further but I am still not able to see it :-(. On roation, yes, the way diagram appears, 'looks' like angle MPS = angle Q'S'T' but I am not able to see why this is happening. e.g. I can see that MP is parallel to Q'S' because earlier they were perpendicular and now we have rotated them by 90 degree. But I don't see why PS will be parallel to S'T', though it does appear parallel in the diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\angle PMT=90°$ by construction and $\angle PST=90°$ by a well-known [property of any conic section](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953161/the-portion-of-the-tangent-to-any-conic-intercepted-between-the-point-of-contact/3953791#3953791). Hence quadrilateral $PSTM$ is cyclic and $\angle PMS=\angle PTS$.

Line $QS$ is perpendicular by construction to $PM$, while $PS\perp ST$ as seen above. Hence $\angle QST=\angle SPM$ because the sides of these angles are pairwise perpendicular. It follows that triangles $QST$ and $SPM$ are similar and $SQ/ST=PS/PM=e=\sqrt2$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If the sides of the angles are pairwise perpendicular then angles will be equal? I am not aware of this. I searched this on google, not getting any specific result. Maybe I need to search with different keywords?

Comment: @aarbee Let's try another way. Produce $SQ$ to meet line $PM$ at $Q'$. Circle $PSQ'$ has diameter $SP$, because $\angle SQ'P=90°$. But $ST\perp SP$, hence $ST$ is tangent to the circle. It follows that $\angle Q'PS=\angle Q'ST$ as both inscribed angles insist on the same arc.

Comment: I think I understood this time. Are we talking about [Alternate Segment Theorem?](https://thirdspacelearning.com/gcse-maths/geometry-and-measure/alternate-segment/)

Comment: @aarbee Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: One doubt. If I make the diagram with point P lower than point Q, then I am not able to apply the alternate segment theorem.

Comment: @aarbee Everything works even in that case, with $Q'$ intersection between lines $SQ$ and $PM$. Just some little changes, which should be evident from the diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Rotating the hyperbola through $-45^{\circ}$ the classic (rectangular) hyperbola with symmetry along axes is obtained and believe  easier to work with further on with a rough sketch.

Eccentricity $e$,  QS on latus rectum, DTM directrix, OD= $a/e$, $OS=a e,~ $ from y-axis.

$$~ a=1; ~ x^2- y^2= 2 a^2 = a^2 e^2;e = \sqrt{2} ;\tag1  $$

A very useful property of conics that may be applied here. Newton's conic, x-axis horizontal.  Standard geometric symbols.

$$ r(1- e \cos \theta)=p; ~~ (r- e \cdot x) =p;$$
Differentiate w.r. arc of conic and use differential relations.

$$ \cos \psi -e \cos \phi =0 $$

$$\boxed{ \frac{\cos \psi}{\cos \phi}= e }\tag 2 $$

We have from cyclic quadrilateral $PMTS$ two angles sum at M

$$ \theta + \psi = \pi/2 \tag 3 $$
and finally

$$ \theta_1=\theta_2=\theta, ~~ \frac{SQ}{ST}=\frac{\sin \theta}{\sin{(\pi/2 -\phi)}} =\frac{\sin \theta }{\cos \phi} $$

$$ = \frac{\cos \psi}{\cos \phi} = e= \sqrt {2}\tag 4 $$

that completes the proof.

It is verified ( same angle subtended on a point opposite a segment) there are three independent angles in *any cyclic quadrilateral*, and the fourth  dependent angle $\pi- ( \theta+ \psi+ \phi ) $

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the hint. I can see that $\theta_1=\theta_2$. Not able to find $\frac{SQ}{ST}$

Comment: Ok. my sketch is hand drawn Paint but suggest a better sketch would on Geogebra, desmos etc. graphing softwares using rotated axes.

Comment: Hey, the sketch is big help. I was just looking for a hint to find the ratio of SQ and ST.

Comment: You know the equation of tangent and where it cuts directrix  & latus rectum. Added another rough sketch but here also a graph mistake. The vertical lines should be ( $ x=1, x=2 $)

Comment: Yes, that is true. I can find the ratio as the coordinates are known. Thanks. The hint above by Intelligenti Pauca seems to suggest we need not use distance formula. If triangles are similar then the ratio is just the eccentricity. But I am not able to prove the similarity of triangles. I can see only one pair of equal angles i.e. $\theta_1=\theta_2$

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I am aware that the ratio of focal distance to the distance from directrix is eccentricity. But I am not aware of the ratio involving cosines. Do you mind giving any link please?

Comment: I  have included derivation which leads to the final  proof.